# Putting variables and line breaks into print statements in Python

Tags: python

I keep getting a syntax error in this code. Can anybody see any formatting errors here?

```
for i in range (10,-1,-1):
    b="green bottles sitting on the wall"
    print(i,b,\n,i,b,\n,"And if one green bottle should accidentally fall"\n"There will be",i,b)
```

Comment: What is `\n` (what python documentation/tutorial do you use, and what does it have to say)?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also, take a look at the syntax error message to know where did the error occurred

Answer (score 1):

Here's the corrected one:

```
for i in range (10,-1,-1):
    b = "green bottles sitting on the wall"
    print(i, b, '\n', i, b, '\nAnd if one green bottle should accidentally fall\nThere will be', i, b)
```

Comment: thanks btw is there any possible way the i in range can just go to 1 not 0. I cant find any other way of changing it. Thanks

Comment: @taylorbriee yes just change (10, -1, -1) to (10,0,-1)

Comment: Use `range (10,0,-1)` in spite of `range (10,-1,-1)`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
print(i,b,"\n",i,b,"\n","And if one green bottle should accidentally fall\nThere willbe",i,b)
```

`\n` should be a string. The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning.

Comment: thanks btw is there any possible way the i in range can just go to 1 not 0. I cant find any other way of changing it. Thanks

Comment: @taylorbriee yes just change (10, -1, -1) to (10,0,-1) 10 is the begin value 0 the value when it shoud stop and -1 the steps it takes

Comment: @taylorbriee because it will stop if the value would get 0 it will only go to 1 as 1-1 would be 0

Comment: @taylorbriee feel free to accept my answer for reputation sake.